# change password change prompts

Tags: centos, rhel

Is there a way for changing a default prompt which is displayed during password change process when password is already expired? on the centos and rhel?
I'd like to change `(current) UNIX password:` to `Your previous password:` or `Enter expired password:`
The original prompt misleads many users who are asking what password they should enter in this step (they already entered old expired password during login, just before this expiration warning and prompt is displayed and it again asks them for old in `(current) UNIX password:`)

```
Changing password for user.
(current) UNIX password:
New password:
Retype new password:
```

Comment: One option is to wrap `passwd` in a bash script and create an alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prompts come from PAM, so you'll have to edit the source code to change their wording.

```
user@host:/tmp/pam-1.1.8$ grep '(current) UNIX password:' -B2 -A3 modules/pam_unix/pam_unix_passwd.c
                        retval = _unix_read_password(pamh, lctrl
                                                     ,Announce
                                             ,_("(current) UNIX password: ")
                                                     ,NULL
                                                     ,_UNIX_OLD_AUTHTOK
                                             ,&pass_old);
user@host:/tmp/pam-1.1.8$ _
```