# Default password prompt change in linux unix

Tags: linux, password

I want to change default password prompt in Linux. Instead of below default prompts, I want to customize the message. What Linux file I need to modify to effect these change?

```
New password: 
Retype new password:
```

e.g:

```
Enter_upper_lower_numberic_password:
Re-Enter_upper_lower_numberic_password:
```

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/439830/117549

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/6095/6216 seems fairly on-point, too.